# How to get make a list of key names from a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I'm taking from a .cvs file, for example:

```
[{'name': 'Tom', 'Age': '15', 'location': 'USA'}, 
{'name': 'Paul', 'Age': '31', 'location': 'UK'},
{'name': 'Tony', 'Age': '24', 'location': 'France'}
]
```

Now say I didn't know what the names of the different keys were, how would I create a list of them, as per my example, specifically a list of ['name', 'age', 'location']? Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion in your question between "key" and "value". Also, if you have a CSV at the start, why not get what you want directly from it rather than go through a less convenient format, such as this dict?

Comment: A list of values of dict "d" can be retrieved with "list(d.values())".

Comment: You're right I am getting myself confused here, so what I'm actually looking for is a list of keys? I figured I'd do it this way because I'm already taking the data from the CVS file to store here, is it really more convenient to take them straight from the CVS file?

Comment: Your csv reader object has a [fieldnames](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.fieldnames) attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Thierry Lathuille for the pointers, I actually figured out 2 different ways to do it, I can either use the csv.fieldname attribute while I have the file open as Thierry recommended, or I can use file[0].keys() from the completed list as keys will be the same for all entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
values_of_key = [key for a_dict in list_of_dicts for key in a_dict.keys()]
values_of_key = list(dict.fromkeys(values_of_key))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).